# How can I get when the client clicks a href in Chrome/Mozilla ...?

Tags: c#, process.start

I need to create an application in C# that will allow me, when the client clicks on a hyperlink, to get that value and execute an executable.

I see the program Webrun. But I'm not sure if it's safe or not.
I would also like to limit it to a single browser URL and pass parameters to run it with `Process.Start`.

This is to open a folder in an internal network so that users through this web application can enter that folder.

I'm sorry for my English.
And thanks for all the help!

Comment: What kind of framework do you use? e.g. asp.net mvc

Comment: My appweb is using PHP & Jquery. My idea is put a C# webform in the client side. This program Will be running in background. And when the client click in href of my appweb. The program execute an exe. You can see the program Webrun. Its what i want. But i need to controll in the webform the URL of the client.

Comment: What do you mean by "C# webform"? The razor view or what?

Comment: A program based on c#

Answer (score 0):

I would create very simple asp.net core web application.
You can create a view which only contains the hyperlink, so the `.cshtml`

> C# webform

would look like:

```
<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Blah" asp-route-value="myValue"> Run exe file</a>
```

And the Home controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Blah(string value)
    {
        // here invoke some function which fires the .exe file
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
}
```

It contains two actions The `Index` and `Blah`. Note that you can pass some value to the server side via your hyperlink. It's up to you what you want to pass. Keep in mind this is only an example. When you click the hyperlink you automatically invoke the `Blah` action. Inside the body of this function you can put some logic e.g. you can invoke some service method which fires the .exe file and then redirect back to the home page. It depends on you what you want to do later after a run of the .exe file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir. I have a server where is my appweb. I need to put in the client (Computers in a intranet) for execute a program(explorer.exe in this case) in the client side. I'm sorry if I explained wrong. So when then client click in the web (Open Explorer). The program execute the method Process.Start